# How to programatically add data to field in AtTask custom form

Tags: attask

I have a large data set of text from outside of AtTask that is changing often.  I need to constrain an AtTask custom form field to this data set.

I was thinking about writing a job that runs periodically to pull the data from the external system and somehow update AtTask with this data using the API.  My first thought was to use a custom enum, but having a custom enum of a thousand or more records that change often doesn't feel right.

What is the recommended approach for accomplishing this?